# Rails missing route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So I have a website for a class.  I am creating a login for the website, so I start with 
"rails generate scaffold User name:string password:digest --no-test-framework" to create the model.
I ran "rake db:migrate" to create the database.

I ran the rails server and opened chrome to check the webpage out by entering the url "localhost:3xxx/users/new" and I get a Routing error that says "No route matches [GET] "/users/new"

I did a "rake routes" to check it out and it is correct, there is no route to "/users/new".

When I ran the generate scaffold I noticed that it did say that it created the route but its not showing up!
Am I missing something?

Comment: also, checked my routes.rb file, nothing in it with the word "user"

Comment: Well, if the output didn't look like the one for [`generate scaffold` n the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate) then something did indeed go wrong. But why not just add it to `routes.rb`?
> resources :users

Comment: The output did look correct, I did end up adding it to routes.rb, I just didn't think about it until after I posted the question :/
still, I am curious why it did look correct but it didn't add the route

Comment: Maybe you had routes.rb open earlier, ran the rake and then saved it (some editor do that automatically) and thus overwriting the change from rake.

Comment: thats possible, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I manually added get "user/new" => "users#new" to the routes.rb file and it worked!

I'm new to rails and usually whenever I use generate scaffold I never get this problem.

If anyone knows how or why the route wasn't added when I used the generate scaffold, please let me know for future reference, thanks!